# How can I pass a variable from one job to another in GitLab CI if jobs are in the same stage?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

According to the [GitLab docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job) you can pass variables between jobs but I've found that doesn't work if the jobs are part of the same stage in the CI/CD pipeline.

How can I share a variable between jobs in the same stage of the pipeline?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `needs:` to declare dependencies between jobs even in the same stage. This can also be used for passing dotenv variable artifacts.

```
jobA:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "FOO=value" > vars.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: vars.env

jobB:
  stage: test
  needs: [jobA]
  script:
    - echo '$FOO'"is ${FOO}"
    # echos '$FOO is value'
```

Answer (score 1):

Jobs in the same stage can run in parallel so I do not think that is possible.

The solution you refer to is based on jobs artifacts. Artifacts are for sharing result with jobs in the following stages.

If you separate the jobs into two stages, you can share results. You can create as many stages as you want. Or you can use a DAG pipeline.